# Eclipse and JRE (JDK)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Version: Luna M6 Release (4.4.0M6)).
My installed JRE: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0.
Problem: http://s30.postimg.org/c02xpcwgx/Capture.png
("The current workspace uses 1.4 JRE...")
And i have got in eclipse Compiler compliance level: 1.7 (why not 1.8?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse 4.4 Luna Milestone 6 does not have Java 8 support. You need a build later than 18th March from the Eclipse [downloads](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) page. This means using an integration build which will have had less testing that the milestone build.

See also [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler)

Comment: And where i can download Eclipse: Java EE IDE for Web Developers for Java 8?

Comment: Your best bet is to get Kepler SR2 and install the Java 8 patch linked above. The result would be more stable than using a Luna I-Build.

Comment: @user3302786 Luna is still under development and doesn't have the integrated builds yet. As in the previous comment use Kepler 4.3.2 and install the Java 8 patch.